# Use C# for Catia V5 Automation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, com, catia

I want to write Macros/Programs for Catia V5 with the programming language C#.

How is it possible to access the Catia applicataion via c#(and Visual Studio). I searched a bit and found out that Catia provides an API, which the Microsoft COM Technologie provides for 'COM-languages' like c# & python.

This is how I imagine the connection/interaction between a C# Programm and Catia:

***C# - .NET <-bi-directional integration-> COM <-> Catia API***

Is that correct ?

Also: How do I setup everything in Visual Studio , so that I can access the Catia API (and code completion etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Add `INFITF` typelib library in reference which is interface to CATIA application

2) Define CATIA as global variable as like

```
   INFITF.Application CATIA;
```

3) Bind the catia application to your `CATIA` variable as below statement

```
   CATIA = (INFITF.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Catia.Application");
```

Hope this would helps you to get started.

Comment: Thanks, you are the best !   Whre can I download the INFITF library ? I  have foun this instruction called "How to: Add References to Type Libraries" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwawt96c(v=vs.110).aspx).  And don't know how to do the first step "1.Install the COM DLL or EXE file on your computer, unless a Windows Setup.exe file performs the installation for you."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Add the `INFITF` typelib library in reference, which is an interface to the CATIA application
2. `INFITF.Application CATIA;`
3. Create Button inside; e.g.,

   ```
   Private void buttonX(object sender, EventArgs e){
       CATIA.Visible = true;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. ***Adding reference to CSProj***:

As suggested by Selin Raja M; you have to "Add INFITF typelib library in references which is the interface to CATIA application (CATIA V5 InfInterfaces Object Library)".
Simply follow: **Project --> References --> Add ---> COM --> CATIA V5 InfInterfaces Object Library**

2. **Binding the CATIA Application and Using inside CSProj**

   ```
    using INFITF; 
    namespace SampleCatiaProj {
       public class LoadDocumentClass {
             public static INFITF.Application CATIA;
             public bool LoadDoc() {     
                CATIA = INFITF.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("CATIA.Application");
                CATIA.Visible = true;
                CATIA.DisplayFileAlerts = true;

                ProductStructureTypeLib.ProductDocument oRootProductDocument;
                oRootProductDocument = (ProductStructureTypeLib.ProductDocument)CATIA.ActiveDocument;

                // Some code goes here

                // Keep on adding code as per CATIA V5 automation API

                return true;
          }
       }
    }
   ```

For practice programs, refer to this [link](https://github.com/nsaori/Catia-v5-Automation)