# c# CATIA Create products and parts

Tags: c#, catia

I'm want to create GUI app in winforms c# that can create a product and parts in Catia v5. (by click on button for example)

Where can I read about this or maybe someone has a code?

Comment: There's an answer here which shows you how to connect to Catia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620334/use-c-sharp-for-catia-v5-automation

Comment: @GisMofx i read this post. this is connect to CATIA. But i need info about creation parts and products

Comment: Best way to start, IMO, is record a VBA macro in Catia and look at the code. Then, you can convert to C#. Come back with some code and we can better help you.

Comment: Read the V5Automation.chm from the CATIA Binaries directory to get an overview over the API.